# "That name is not valid" for my VBA function in Excel/Mac

Tags: macos, vba, excel

A simple VBA function. When I try to use it in my worksheet, all I get, no matter what I do, is "That name is not valid". I'm out of ideas.

```
Sub FindABV(temperature)
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("C28").GoalSeek _
    Goal:=temperature, _
    ChangingCell:=.Range("B28")
End With
FindABV = .Range("B28").Value
End Sub
```

I've tried creating a new Module to put it in. No change. 
And no error indications from the code editor.

Comment: `Sub`? Or did you want it as `Public Function FindABV(temperature)`?

Comment: You may want to see [This](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/function-sub.html)

Comment: @SiddharthRout is correct.  You have to define it as a function if you want to use in a `Formula`.  However, you're cell references are hard-coded so it probably won't work as you intend.

Comment: You are not going to be able have a fully functioning UDF that changes values in cells other than the cell in which it resides.

Answer (score 0):

> The Sub procedure performs a task and then returns control to the calling code, but it does not return a value to the calling code.

See more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/831f9wka.aspx).

This said, you cannot set a procedure equal to something:

```
FindABV = .Range("B28").Value
```

because *that name is not valid* (you cannot say that a procedure is equal to a certain value, it doesn't make sense). You probably wanted to use a [Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sect4ck6.aspx) to return the value of that cell calculated by the Goal Seeker depending on the input `temperature` that you pass by the function:

```
Function FindABV(temperature)
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("C28").GoalSeek _
    Goal:=temperature, _
    ChangingCell:=.Range("B28")
End With
FindABV = .Range("B28").Value '<-- return the value
End Function
```

However, be careful: if `=FindABV(temperature)` lies on `Sheet1.Range("B28")`, you will have a circular reference because your function will try to have the value of itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will not deliver the results you want.  If you want to have the `Function` work for different values than the ones stored in `B28` and `C28` you'll have to write it more like this:

```
Public Function FindABV(goalCell As Range, changeCell As Range, temperature As Double)

    goalCell.GoalSeek Goal:=temperature, ChangingCell:=changeCell

    FindABV = changeCell
End Function
```

But this doesn't matter in any case because `GoalSeek` actually changes the value in the `ChangingCell` which `Excel` will not do if it is called from within a `Function`.

Comment: Thanks for that insight! I wasn't aware that a Function can't change a value in a cell. That would appear to mean that what I'm trying for is hopeless. Is there some other way to make GoalSeek work as a callable function?

Comment: Interestingly, Excel is perfectly happy to change cell values when called by AppleScript. But I was hoping to create a calculator that I could share even with Windows users.

Comment: You could always perform the operation that Excel performs in `GoalSeek` yourself by stepping up to the value in very small increments until you overshoot and then return the closest value.

Comment: Yes, I actually searched for some code I could borrow to do this kind of iterative solution, but wasn't able to find anything. Seems like it ought to be available somewhere. I don't know VBA well enough to try it myself without extensive study. (Can you pass a function as a parameter to a VBA routine?) I've seen mention of something called "Solver"—is that potentially usable?

Comment: If the function you are solving is always the same you can use Newton's Method to solve it.  If the function changes you'll have to devise an approach with events and macros.